# how to open R document in rampant logic postscript viewer?

Tags: r, postscript, viewer, tinn-r

I save a file using `Tinn R` and try to open it in rampant logic postscript viewer 1.1 but it is opening in word pad. I am unable to understand the problem. My code is given below

```
library(MASS)
attach(cats)
#print(cats)
#names(cats)
#summary(cats)
postscript("asd.ps",horizontal=F)
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
boxplot(cats[,2:3])
plot(Bwt,Hwt)
```

Comment: Without `dev.off()`, your PostScript file is likely to be incomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to close the device before R finalises the file (and before it even draws on the device), e.g.

```
postscript("asd.ps", horizontal=FALSE)
op <- par(mfrow=c(2,2))
boxplot(cats[,2:3])
plot(Bwt, Hwt)
par(op)
dev.off() ## close the device
```

Once you've dealt with that, make sure `.ps` files are associated with the Rampant Logic viewer rather than with Wordpad. IIRC, `.ps` default to being handled by Wordpad (at least they did the last time I used Windows...)